# How to create a recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

Earlier I have created a recursive program in Java where I had a scenario in which there is a `Folder` and that folder has a set of `File's` and some `Folder's` (Please note that the actual scenario is different, it was not Folder and Files). So whenever I find a folder in program I used to call my function recursively to read the Files and Folders in it till I find no more folders.

This was the code I have written earlier:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Filewalker {

    public void walk( String path ) {

        File root = new File( path );
        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        if (list == null) return;

        for ( File f : list ) {
            if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
                walk( f.getAbsolutePath() );
                System.out.println( "Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
            }
            else {
                System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Filewalker fw = new Filewalker();
        fw.walk("C:\\Java" );
    }

}
```

Now I am given a new assignment where the scenario is like this:

A `Folder` is having just `File's` and I was asked to prepare a recursive function on this. Now I am good at preparing a program where I read the folder and the files in it. But, in this case there are no sub-folders, so I was not able to find out how to prepare a recursive scenario to develop my Java program.

Can you please guide me how to prepare recursive program in such use case? Is it possible?

Comment: Show us what you've done so far. post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: This is a question better answered by the person setting the assignment. You can ask them why they want to use recursion when there is no good reason to do so.

Comment: Recursion is not required here. It's a great technique to use only when the depth is not known from the beginning.

Comment: @Madhan, added code, please check

Comment: @david.lucky, The number of files in the folder is not known initially, so does be a reason for recursion?

Comment: @user3181365 no, though the number of files is not known you can simply call for .listFiles() to get them all; there is no "depth" here

Comment: Your code will work for second case also.can you explain more on your second problem.What do you want to do with the 3 files from a folder?

Comment: @Madhan, The requirement is just to read details about the file, for example the name of the file and who created it etc

Comment: @Madhan, yes the code will work but this time the assignment is different and I have just unknown number of files in a Folder, this time I will not have sub-folders

Comment: Remove the if else inside for loop and print the details..There is no recursion needed

Comment: @Madhan, ok that is what my question was, how to implement recursion in this use-case

Comment: @Madhan, Please check the accepted answer, recursion is still possible in this case.

Comment: Ya that's possible. but it is nothing but `for loop` as a function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write *any* recursive function you need to define a condition that is your stop point.
When you identify that condition then you either stop or do some processing logic that depends on recursion.
Whether you have only 3 files or N files is irrelevant. All you need to do is define the steps of processing in recursive manner that you can stop the recursion by having a clear condition that ends it.

The actual requirement of your assignment is not clear to me.
There are many ways to approach the statement `A Folder is having just 3 File's and I was asked to prepare a recursive function on this.`
An example:

```
public void processFile(File[] files, int index) {
   if(index < 0 || index >= files.length) return;
   File fileToProcess = files[index];  
   //processing logic   
   processFile(files, index + 1);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I have the idea about the recursion, but how can I implement it for my scenario explained?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I have done the homework but got stuck on how to use recursion here. So came here for correct approach, sorry if it hurts anyone

Comment: +1 The code in your answer seems good for my usecase, I will try this approach and see if it fits in my program. Thanks a lot